# REST API stays even composite application is undeployed

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

Using WSO2EI 6.4.0 Integrator (ESB). We develop a composite application containing some proxies, sequences and rest api definitions.

We intend to deploy the carbon app (.car) using the [maven-car-deploy-plugin](https://docs.wso2.com/display/DVS370/Deploying+a+CAR+File+with+the+Maven+Plug-In) or we could just copy the carbon app into the server/carbonapps folder.

After some updates we'd like to redeploy the application (undeploy the old application, deploy a new one).  After undeploying the carbon app, the carbon app disappear, the proxies disappear, but the rest apis stay (visible in /carbon/api/index.jsp).

The consequence is that new definitions (from the new car file) are not deployed. Is it a bug, or a feature, or I am missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't experienced any of this in integrator but in the old ESB (4.8.1) I've seen this behavior before, I can only give pointers:

- check if there is any file resembling the name of the project or the
  name of the API that stays around after removal. Might be that this
  is messing up your undeployments. Remove those files and try again.
- Always deploy locally to see if there are errors during deployment.
  Usually this sort of behavior starts when the deployment goes wrong.